# How to get dynamically created DropDownList's ID and check if its value changed or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented a view in which dynamic number of textboxes and DropDownList are generated, by the help of [Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). All works fine. But I want that untill each dropdownlist has a value, form could not be submitted and also if there is no dropdownlist I mean all dynamic content deleted, then form MUST not be submit.

Main View Code:

```
<div id="Part2">
 <h3><u>Services:</u></h3><br />
 <div id="EditorRows">
  <%Html.RenderPartial("_InsertServices", Model);%>
 </div>
 <div id="DontAppend">
  <%= Html.ActionLink("+ Add Another Service", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" }) %>
  <input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" hidden="hidden"/>
  <input type="button" id="btnDone" value="Done" />
 </div>
</div>
```

PartialVew Code:

```
<div class="EditorRow">
 <% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("services")){ %>
 <table id="table1">
  <tr>
   <td>NOS:</td>
   <td><%:Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Id,(SelectList)ViewData["crmServiceType"] as SelectList,"---")%></td>
   <td>Comment:</td>
   <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comment, new { size = "20" })%></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<% } %>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
  url: this.href,
  cache: false,
  success: function (html) { $("#EditorRows").append(html); }
  });
  return false;
});
$("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
  $(this).parents("div.EditorRow:first").remove();
  return false;
});
```

[Here](http://pastie.org/6409364) is generated HTML Source.

Comment: Make use of "on" instead of "live", cos its deprecated in latest versions

Comment: Please post rendered HTML

Comment: `.live()` is a deprecated function. Use `.on()` instead. See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @peterm, I Have put link of generated HTML. You can view it now.

Comment: @djIT Your generated html doesn't contain markup for dropdown boxes

Comment: @peterm, It there the SELECT tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and your markup looks like

```
<div class="EditorRow">
    <input type="hidden" value="6c2fa95a-cc3e-44d9-b460-b561276196c1" autocomplete="off" name="services.index">
    <table id="table1">
    <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Value1</option>
        <option value="2">Value2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

you can do it like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnDone").click(function(){
        if ($("div.EditorRow").length) {
            $("div.EditorRow select").each(function(){
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    alert("You need to choose a value before submit");
                    return false;
                }
                //do your submit
            });
        } else {
            alert("You need to add at least one service before submit.")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` was deprecated and `now removed in jQuery version 1.9+` so use `.on()` handler instead.
Not sure why you added `:first`, What i am guessing that you have multiple `EditorRow` divs if that is the case then you should try this:

```
 $("#EditorRows").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function () {
    var selID = $(this).closest("div.EditorRow").find('select').attr('id'); //<--give you the select list id
    $(this).closest("div.EditorRow").andSelf().remove();
    return false;
 });
```

Dont know where you want this but you can achieve with this way:

```
$("#EditorRows").find('select').attr('id');
```

Comment: I dont know why but on is not working for me though I am using jquery 1.9.

Comment: Have you tried to delegate the click event like mine one? `EditorRows` or you can delegate to `document`.

Comment: Actually MY QUESTION is I want to check if dropdownlist's value is selected or not. By default id is 0, It must be greater than>0 while user select the value.

Comment: It is just serving the purpose of deletion. And that was already working using live. I want to check if dropdownlist value is selected or not. For that I need dropdownlist 's ID. which I dont know how to get.

Comment: but you have not pasted that stuff here and not in the pastebin `(select)`.

Comment: I am saying that it is generating dynamic ID and I dont know hw to get it.

Comment: Ah i see, one more thing you want that when click on delete link only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25745/discussion-between-djit-and-jai)

Comment: @djIT i am on a network currently which has blocked all the chat or discussion sites and forum.

Comment: although i have updated a line in the second one, see if that helps you getting the id.

Comment: ok it is giving me id. But of deleting item. Thanks for that. bt can i get id of new created element?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Petern code works perfectly for me. Also your code helps me lot.